# List of Flights

Tags: javascript

I got this question to solve.

***you're given a list of flights start and end times. determine the maximum amount of airplanes in the air at the same time***

**Example**

```
  {start:4, end:9},
  {start:2, end:5},
  {start:17, end:20},
  {start:10, end:21},
  {start:9, end:18},
 return 3
```

so as you can see I have to return 3 because there are three airplanes in the air at the same time. `start:9, end:18 and start:10, end:21 and start:17, end:20` those are three airplanes in the air at the same time.

This is my code

```
 const arr = [
  {start:4, end:9},
  {start:2, end:5},
  {start:17, end:20},
  {start:10, end:21},
  {start:9, end:18},
] 
const flights = flite => {
  let final = []
  flite.sort((a,b) => a.start - b.start)
  for(let i = 0; i < flite.length; i++) {
    let st = flite[i]
    if(st.end > st.start) return final.push(st.start)
  }
  return final
}

flights(arr)
```

Comment: Hi - there doesn't actually seem to be a question here?

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like below and you will get your result.

```js
const arr = [
  {start:4, end:9},
  {start:2, end:5},
  {start:17, end:20},
  {start:10, end:21},
  {start:9, end:18},
];

const flights = flite => {
  // reduce will iterate through each value and produce single result.      
  // reduce has two params, callback function and initialValue : optional.
  // here I have call back function (a, i) => {...}
  // add initialValue = 0, so for first iteration it will have a = 0.
  // inside callback function filtering array with flight start time between current timing's start and end. And returning max value between a and filter.length
  return flite.reduce((a, i) => Math.max(a, flite.filter(x => x.start >= i.start && x.start <= i.end).length) , 0);
}

console.log(flights(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is amazing.